# AWS Elastic Map Reduce Hive running v0.5? missing functions: 'str_to_map' , 'reflect'

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr

In Amazon AWS's Elastic Map Reduce implementation of Hive, the UDFs `str_to_map` and `reflect` are not defined.

str_to_map is documented here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

and was released with Hive 0.7: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1779

But when running Hive in AWS EMR, `show functions` does not show `str_to_map` or `reflect` as a supported function.

So, it appears that the EMR EC2 nodes have hive-0.5 installed.

```
hadoop@ip-....:~$ sudo find  / -name "hive-exec*jar"
/home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.5/lib/hive-exec-0.5.0.jar

hadoop@...:~$ ls /home/hadoop/.versions/
0.18  0.20  hive-0.5
```

That seems... wrong.

I am pretty sure Hive 0.7 is in EMR. How do I get an AMI with Hive 0.7 on the EMR EC2 master node?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I needed to upgrade to the lastest EMR Ruby CLI, and pass "--hive-versions 0.7.1" on the command line.

https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2264